# How to resize epiphany web-browser

Tags: raspbian, terminal, web-browsers

I would like to automatically resize the window just after starting the system. Until now I achieve to start the browser automatically after the start just by adding the following code.

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@epiphany-browser http://www.google.de
```

Lets say I want that the windows size be half of the screen. How can I achieve it? I heard about geometry, but how to use it?

update: Unfortunately, geometry is not supported by epiphany. Any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

In the man page there is:

> -l, --load-session=FILE
>
> > Load the given session file

There may be something in the session file that determines screen size

Answer (score 1):

> I heard about geometry, but how to use it?

Not all GUI apps have this, but if they do it is generally of the format:

```
-geometry WidthxHeight+Xoffset+Yoffset
```

E.g., `-geometry 800x300+200+0`.  The offsets are optional but if you want one you must use both.  You can use negative offsets.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crazy idea and is absolutely not the 'right' way to do things, but;-

You can use the `xdotool` command to simulate mouse movement and clicks. Once Epiphany has started, you might be able to script a way to click and drag the size of the window.

See [this page](http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse) for more info.